# VS Load Tests in azure with private TFS

Tags: azure, tfs, load-testing

I have a private TFS (2017) which is **not** hosted in Azure, but I want to run Visual Studio load tests in the cloud:

[image]

But when I click this option I get this error message:

[image]

What is the requirement I'm missing here? What kind of resource do I need to create in Azure if it's even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot run Load Tests in the cloud with on-premise TFS (private TFS).

You should  use the Azure DevOps (VSTS) to do that. Please see [Load test your app in the cloud using Visual Studio and Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/getting-started-with-performance-testing?view=vsts) for details.

You can also [run cloud-based load tests directly using the Azure DevOps portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/get-started-simple-cloud-load-test?view=vsts), or [run load tests locally with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/quickstart-create-a-load-test-project?view=vs-2017), or [run Load tests with the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/app-service-web-app-performance-test?view=vsts).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to run my load tests with Azure devops.